# How to draw a grey textbox next to aligned equations?

Tags: equations

[image: picture]

how to do the same option in the red box below in the equation?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried? Please, provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I'll use tikz for that.

Comment: I have no ideas for that :((

Comment: you want to add text in each line of the equations?

Comment: @Nicolas, no i wonder how we can add like the RHS (the red box)

Comment: What would the red box contain?

Comment: @Bernard, the same!

Comment: Should the red  box  be closed, and its contents in the margin?

Comment: I would try to find in the tcolorbox doc the way to create a new king of  equation environnement, with the RHS as argument...  I'm not using it enough to provide an example, the doc can be found on CTAN and contains a lot of exemples. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox

Comment: Actually, thanks so much all of you, but I would like to make it clearly: 1. what I want is NOT the red box!! 2. what i want I how to make the left small title (the same in the red box I draw) in Latex!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fit your needs?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    We will describe\ldots
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{flalign}
    \tikz \node [fill=gray,fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1, minimum width=15ex]{\tiny Incident wawe};&& E_i & = E_{i0}&\\
    \tikz \node [fill=gray,fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1, minimum width=15ex]{\tiny Reflected wawe};&& E_r & = E_{r0}&\\
    \tikz \node [fill=gray,fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1, minimum width=15ex]{\tiny Transmitted wawe};&& E_t & = E_{t0}&
    \end{flalign}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but maybe I will try to improve! many thanks !!!!!!